# "as did copies of writings that"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Heidegger responded to this expression of philosophical comradeship with gratitude, and for the next year a flurry of letters passed between them, **as did copies of writings that**, by that point, reflected utterly different approaches.

May be I'm wrong but I presume that the core of the above sentence is: *Heidegger responded to this expression of philosophical comradeship with gratitude, and for the next year flurry of letters passed  between them reflected utterly different approaches*; and the bold passage is some sort of parenthesis but I am not able to decipher what is mean by this part. Does it mean that we have at disposal only copies of the letters?

Answer (score 2):

You've got the first part of the sentence pretty well.  The main point to understand is that "as did copies of writings" is not a parenthetical, but a phrase that essentially means "also copies of writings".  "By that point" is parenthetical to that phrase!

I would rephrase the sentence this way:

**Heidegger responded to this expression of philosophical comradeship with gratitude, and for the next year a flurry of letters passed between them**
(note that it should be "a flurry")

**and also passing between them were copies of writings**
(I am not 100% sure what the author means by "copies of writings".  I suspect it means "copies of papers that Heidegger and the other person had each written".)

**and at that time**

**the copies of writings reflected utterly different approaches.**

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. So if I understand well, it was the copies of writings that reflected utterly different approaches and not the letters.

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 1):

I understand it as "*...for the next year they exchanged letters and other copies of writing that reflected utterly different approaches*", where the letters are letters written by one of the men to the other, and "copies of writings" would be things written by others that they agree with, like books or newspaper articles or something.